# Como me puede mostrar datos de una tabla de sql en un InputSelect en blazor server

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Tengo dos tablas la primera: dbo.Article con sus campos Id, Title, CategoryId, Price.

y la segunda: dbo.Category con sus campos Id, Name, Description.

Quiero que pueda seleccionar las categorias que tengo el la tabla Category
al momento que ingrese un producto
estoy trabajando con mi dataacces que es un proyecto de libreria de clases donde llevo mis modelos y mi coneccion a la base de datos

hasta el momento llevo esto:

```
//Esto esta en mi dataAcces
 public Task<List<ArticleModels>> GetArticle()
    {
        string sql = "Select * from dbo.Article  ";
        return _db.LoadData<ArticleModels, dynamic>
            (sql, new
            { });

    }

    public Task InsertArticle(ArticleModels article)
    {
        string sql = " insert into dbo.Article (Title,CategoryId,Price)" +
            "values(Title=@Title,CategoryId=@CategoryId,Price=@Price) set @Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

        return _db.SaveData(sql, article);

    }
```

Y en mi pagina dentro de Blazor Server APP llevo esto

```
@page "/Data/CreateArticle"

@using FerrDataAccess.Models
@using FerrDataAccess.Data
@using BlazorServer.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

@inject IArticleData _db
@inject ICategoryData _ca

<h3>CreateArticle</h3>
<h4>Articulos</h4>

<EditForm Model="@newArticle" OnValidSubmit="@InsertArticle">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            label {
                width: 100px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <InputText @bind-Value="newArticle.Title"></InputText>
    
//No se como llama mi lista de categorias 
//en el bloque de codigo explico mejor
    <InputSelect @bind-Value="catelist"></InputSelect>


        <InputNumber @bind-Value="newArticle.Price"></InputNumber>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>

</EditForm>

@if (article is null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var arti in article)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@arti.Title</td>
                    <td>@arti.CategoryId</td>
                    <td>@arti.Price</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
}


@code {
    private List<ArticleModels> article;

public List<SelectListItem> catelist { get; set; }



    private DisplayArticleModels newArticle = new DisplayArticleModels();


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        article = await _db.GetArticle();



 //Esto es segun para obtner la categoria conforme el Id
//pero nose como ponerlo dentro de mi InputSelect
        var cate = await _ca.GetCategory();
        catelist = new List<SelectListItem>();

        cate.ForEach(
            x =>
            {
                catelist.Add(
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                        Text = x.Name
                    });
            });
    }

    //insertar
    private async Task InsertArticle()
    {
        ArticleModels a = new ArticleModels
        {
            Title = newArticle.Title,
            CategoryId = newArticle.Id,
            Price = newArticle.Price

        };
        await _db.InsertArticle(a);
        article.Add(a);

        newArticle = new DisplayArticleModels();
    }

    



     



}
```

Nota: ESTOY TRABAJANDO CON APLICACIÓN DE BLAZOR SERVER ASP.NET CORE 3.1 PLIS AYUDENME !!!

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Y ala formule mejor pero nesesito ayuda deverdad

Answer (score 0):

No se si estoy entendiendo bien. Quieres un InputSelect de un lista que sacas de una tabla de bbdd? Si es así
creando un objeto como la tabla y haciendo la select, seria algo así.

```
@code {

    private IEnumerable<CLIENTES> clienteLista;
  
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            clienteLista = await ClientesService.GetAllCliente();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

propuesta es el objeto que has tenido que crear previamente

```
 <div class="col-sm-7">
      <InputSelect id="rutat" @bind-Value="propuesta.RUTA" class="form-control" name="rutat">
        <option value="null">- Seleccionar -</option>
            @foreach (var ruta in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Ruta)))
                 {
                  <option value="@ruta">@ruta</option>
                 }
           </InputSelect>
  </div>
```

ya te vas creando en GetAllCliente() las ordenes de crear la select que necesitas. luego con el dato que necesitas haces las cosas que quieres hacer con el dato elegido.